# Azure DevOps CICD - Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan

Tags: azure, terraform, cicd, hashicorp

Im using terraform to deploy the infrastructure.Infra is already deployed and up an running. So I wanted to run the CICD pipeline for the Infrasturcture.

But I get the error - **Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan**. Specifically, when its reading the access connector resource API throws the bed request (400), Identity not found.

I tried to `terraform plan` in vscode and it did not produce any error.

Im not sure what causes the problem.

If you need more information that might be crucial and I missed to say it (Im new to CICD and terraform), happy to add it to my description.

Answer (score 0):

> Terraform Errors in CI/CD Environments: Key Strategies and Resources.

A possible reason for the Terraform error in your CI/CD pipeline, but not in VS Code, is that the environment or configuration is not the same for both setups.

Here are some steps and considerations to help troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. **Ensure Environment Consistency**: To avoid inconsistency, make sure your local setup and the CI/CD environment have the same Terraform and provider versions. Different versions can cause unexpected behavior.
   .
2. **Verify Credentials and Identity**: A common cause of the "Identity not found" error is authentication problems. Check that your CI/CD pipeline has the correct credentials and permissions to access the resources it needs.
3. **Check Terraform State Access**: State files are essential for Terraform to manage resources. Errors may occur if your CI/CD pipeline cannot access the right state file. Provide consistent access to state files across environments.
4. **Review and Set Environment Variables**: Your CI/CD environment may need some environment variables for your Terraform configurations. Make sure you set all the required environment variables correctly in your CI/CD environment.
5. **Analyze CI/CD Pipeline Configuration**:The order and commands of your CI/CD pipeline can influence the execution of Terraform. Check the pipeline settings for possible problems.

These points should help you identify and resolve the discrepancy causing the Terraform error in your CI/CD pipeline.

**Reference:**

- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/version-constraints
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/auth
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/docs